# Jira API Set Pending Reason

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

Using the Jira API I'm trying to set a Pending Reason. I've dug out the following from the schema:

```
"customfield_15072":
      {
        "required":false,
        "schema":
        {
          "type":"option",
          "custom":"com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select",
          "customId":15072
        },
        "name":"Pending reason",
        "key":"customfield_15072",
        "operations":["set"],
        "allowedValues":
        [
          {"self":"https://url/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/15100","value":"More info required","id":"15100"}
        ]
      }
```

So I'm updating the following custom field using a PUT to the ticket (e.g. domain/issue/TICKET-234)

```
{"fields":{"customfield_15072":"15100"}}
```

But I keep getting told that this is is not valid for the customfield.

```
responseText: 
`{"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_15072":"Specify a valid 'id' or 'name' for Pending reason"}}`,
```

Can anyone point me in the direction as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The data needed to be in this format:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "customfield_15072": {
            "id": "15100"
        }
    }
}
```